# Add rowwise n in table using gtsummary

Tags: r, gtsummary

I am trying to show the percent survival for each category of pulmonary artery pressure.  My data looks like this:

```
library(tibble)
library(gtsummary)

data<-tribble(
  ~cat, ~status,
  "0-20", "Alive",
  "0-20", "Deceased",
  "20-40", "Alive",
  "20-40", "Alive",
  "20-40", "Alive"
)
```

When I do the add_n() at the end, it gives me an N for the total cohort.  I'd like it to show the total n for each level - i.e. instead of saying N=5, I'd like it to say 2 for "0-20" and 3 for "20-40".

```
data %>% tbl_summary(
  by=status,
  missing="no",
  percent="row") %>%
  modify_column_hide(stat_2) %>%
  add_n()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need `add_overall()`

```
library(dplyr)
library(gtsummary)

data %>% tbl_summary(
  by=status,
  missing="no",
  percent="row") %>%
  add_overall()
```

[image]

Comment: Kind of - that will work, except I'm also stacking two of the tables on top of each other, so I need the N's for each of the rows - not just the top row.  Here's what I get with tbl_stack - it drops the n's for the VV Ecmo and just uses the header for the first table:  https://imgur.com/a/QEIhzpf